# Forma D:HH:MM:SS para cantidad de tiempo ya calculada en Python

Tags: python, formato

Estoy tratando de resolver un ejercicio para principiantes, pero me topé con un problema, el problema con el ejercicio es esta parte:
"... then your program should display the equivalent amount of time in the form D:HH:MM:SS..."
Tengo un código que toma una cantidad de segundos y los convierte en días, horas, etc y quiero que esos datos tengan la forma que dice el ejercicio pero no sé como.
He tratado con el módulo <> pero no lo consigo.
¿Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Pista: utiliza el modulo `datetime`.

Comment: Por favor adjunta el código que has intentado y lo que has investigado para que te podamos ayudar, si no lo has hecho, hazlo y te podemos resolver las dudas al respuesto. Las preguntas que piden resolver ejercicios sin ningún trabajo de investigación no suelen ser bien recividas por la comunidad.

Comment: Formatea una cadena, por ejemplo: `f"{dias}:{horas}:{minutos}:{segundos}"`, y antes de hacerlo comprueba si los valores de *horas*, *minutos* y *segundos* tienen uno o dos dígitos (si tiene un dígito añades un *cero* a la izquierda)